# Click outside menu to close in jquery

Tags: jquery

So I have a drop-down menu that shows on a click, as per business requirements. The menu becomes hidden again after you mouse away from it.

But now I am being asked to have it stay in place until user clicks anywhere on the document. How can this be accomplished?

This is a simplified version of what I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.opMenu li").click(function(){
   $('#MainOptSubMenu',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
  });

  $("ul.opMenu li").mouseleave(function(){
      $('#MainOptSubMenu',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});



<ul  class="opMenu">
  <li id="footwo" class="">
    <span id="optImg" style="display: inline-block;"> <img src="http://localhost.vmsinfo.com:8002/insight/images/options-hover2.gif"/> </span>
      <ul id="MainOptSubMenu" style="visibility: hidden; top: 25px; border-top: 0px solid rgb(217, 228, 250); background-color: rgb(217, 228, 250); padding-bottom: 15px;">
        <li>some</li>
       <li>nav</li>
       <li>links</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried something like this `$('document[id!=MainOptSubMenu]').click(function()` thinking it would trigger on anything that wasnt the menu, but it didnt work.

Comment: I have an answer over here. > [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/43405204#43405204](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/43405204#43405204)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 203):

Take a look at the approach this question used:

[How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

> Attach a click event to the document body which closes the window. Attach a separate click event to the window which stops propagation to the document body.

```
$('html').click(function() {
  //Hide the menus if visible
});

$('#menucontainer').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: its very beautyfull but you should use $('html').click() not body. The body always has the height of its content. It there is not a lot of content or the screen is very high, it only works on the part filled by the body. Copy from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element – meo Feb 25 '11 at 15:35

Comment: great solution. any idea why it works with .click() and not with .live('click', func...?

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that objects which already have a click listener which stopPropagation for other reasons have no effect. I understand why it is so, but it's still a limitation of this solution.

Answer (score 55):

The answer is right, but it will add a listener that will be triggered every time a click occurs on your page. To avoid that, you can add the listener for just one time :

```
$('a#menu-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#menu').toggleClass('open');

    $(document).one('click', function closeMenu (e){
        if($('#menu').has(e.target).length === 0){
            $('#menu').removeClass('open');
        } else {
            $(document).one('click', closeMenu);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: if you want to avoid the `stopPropagation()` on the initial button you can use this

```
var $menu = $('#menu');

$('a#menu-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$menu.hasClass('active')) {
        $menu.addClass('active');

        $(document).one('click', function closeTooltip(e) {
            if ($menu.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('a#menu-link').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $menu.removeClass('active');
            } else if ($menu.hasClass('active')) {
                $(document).one('click', closeTooltip);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $menu.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: I see code like this a lot, wouldn't this add a new click function to the document every time the menu link is clicked?  So if you click the menu link 1000 times without refreshing the page, you'll have 1000 functions taking up memory and also executing?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the "one" function, now I understand why this works: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: nice solution but I had to use `e.stopPropagation()` in Chrome to stop the first event from firing in the `one()` handler

Answer (score 26):

The `stopPropagation` options are bad because they can interfere with other event handlers including other menus that might have attached close handlers to the HTML element.

Here is a simple solution based on *user2989143*'s answer:

```
$('html').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('#menu-container, #menu-activator').length === 0) {
        $('#menu-container').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17):

If using a plugin is ok in you case, then I suggest Ben Alman's clickoutside plugin located [here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/):

its usage is as simple as this:

```
$('#menu').bind('clickoutside', function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

2 options that you can investigate:

- On showing of the menu, place a large empty DIV behind it covering up the rest of the page and give that an on-click event to close the menu (and itself). This is akin to the methods used with lightboxes where clicking on the background closes the lightbox
- On showing of the menu, attach a one-time click event handler on the body that closes the menu. You use jQuery's '.one()' for this.

Answer (score 6):

I found a variant of [Grsmto's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15576211/2615152) and [Dennis' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089622/2615152) fixed my issue.

```
$(".MainNavContainer").click(function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();  // Might cause problems depending on implementation
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(document).one('click', function (e) {
        if(!$(e.target).is('.MainNavContainer')) {
            // code to hide menus
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

what about this?

```
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){  
        var thisUI = $(this);
        $('html').click(function(){
                thisUI.hide();
            $('html').unbind('click');
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this solution with multiple elements with the same behavior in the same page:

```
$("html").click(function(event){
    var otarget = $(event.target);
    if (!otarget.parents('#id_of element').length && otarget.attr('id')!="id_of element" && !otarget.parents('#id_of_activator').length) {
        $('#id_of element').hide();
    }
});
```

stopPropagation() is a bad idea, this breaks standard behaviour of many things, including buttons and links.

Comment: This is great, but you can simplify it as `$target.closest('#menu-container, #menu-activator').length === 0`

Answer (score 5):

I have recently faced the same issue. I wrote the following code:

```
    $('html').click(function(e) {
      var a = e.target;
      if ($(a).parents('.menu_container').length === 0) {
        $('.ofSubLevelLinks').removeClass('active'); //hide menu item
        $('.menu_container li > img').hide(); //hide dropdown image, if any
     }
    });
```

It has worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I find it more useful to use mousedown-event instead of click-event. The click-event doesn't work if the user clicks on other elements on the page with click-events. In combination with jQuery's one() method it looks like this:

```
$("ul.opMenu li").click(function(event){

   //event.stopPropagation(); not required any more
   $('#MainOptSubMenu').show();

   // add one mousedown event to html
   $('html').one('mousedown', function(){
       $('#MainOptSubMenu').hide();
   });
});

// mousedown must not be triggered inside menu
$("ul.opMenu li").bind('mousedown', function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

even i came across the same situation and one of my mentor put this idea across to myself.

**step:1**   when clicked on the button on which we should show the drop down menu. then add the below class name "more_wrap_background" to the current active page like shown below

```
$('.ui-page-active').append("<div class='more_wrap_background' id='more-wrap-bg'> </div>");
```

**step-2**   then add a clicks for the div tag like

```
$(document).on('click', '#more-wrap-bg', hideDropDown);
```

where hideDropDown is the function to be called to hide drop down menu

**Step-3**    and important step while hiding the drop down menu is that remove that class you that added earlier like

```
$('#more-wrap-bg').remove();
```

I am removing by using its id in the above code

```
.more_wrap_background {
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 999;//should be one less than the drop down menu's z-index
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `:visible` css selector to check for when it's not being hovered. Here's a working example :

```html
<button id="menu-btn">
  Menu
</button>
<div id="menu-popup" style="display: none">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$("#menu-btn").on('click', function() {
    $("#menu-popup").toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
    if (!$("#menu-btn:hover").length) {
    $("#menu-popup:not(:hover)").hide();
  }
});
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8em0Lz1d/

Comment: This prevents me from opening the menu

Comment: @Green I updated my answer to include a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("html").click( onOutsideClick );
onOutsideClick = function( e )
{
    var t = $( e.target );
    if ( !(
        t.is("#mymenu" ) ||     //Where #mymenu - is a div container of your menu
        t.parents( "#mymenu" ).length > 0
        )   )
    {
        //TODO: hide your menu
    }
};
```

And better to set the listener only when your menu is being visible and always remove the listener after menu becomes hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BeenYoung/BXaqW/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.opMenu li").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('opened')==false){          
                $('.opMenu').find('.opened').removeClass('opened').find('ul').slideUp();
                $(this).addClass('opened'); 
                $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('opened'); 
                $(this).find("ul").slideUp();               
            }
      });
  });    
});
```

I hope it useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the ':visible' selector.
Where .menuitem is the to-hide element(s) ...

```
$('body').click(function(){
  $('.menuitem:visible').hide('fast');
});
```

Or if you already have the .menuitem element(s) in a var ...

```
var menitems = $('.menuitem');
$('body').click(function(){
  menuitems.filter(':visible').hide('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery and wanted to do it with pure CSS and HTML this is the solution.

- Create a trigger element and inside it write your popup element.
- Attach a click handler to unhide the popup on the click of the trigger element.
- Have a backdrop element that stretches to the entire screen width and attach click handlers to that which hides the popup.
- All attached click handlers should stop the event from propagating so other handlers are not called.

Find live code below

```js
function showPopup(bShow,args){
  var popupContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('popup-container')[0];
  debugger;
  if(!bShow){
    popupContainer.classList.add('hide-element')
  }else{
    popupContainer.classList.remove('hide-element')
  }
  args[0].stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.popup-trigger{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.backdrop{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.actual-popup{
}
.popup-container{
 top: 30px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 background: grey;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
}

.hide-element{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">

  <div onclick="showPopup(true,arguments)" class="popup-trigger">Click to open dialog with button
    <div onclick="showPopup(false,arguments)" class='popup-container hide-element'> 
     <div onclick="showPopup(false,arguments)" class='backdrop'>  </div>
     <div onclick="showPopup(true,arguments)" class='actual-popup'> 
        <button onclick="showPopup(false,arguments)"> close me </button>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks through these answers and this is how i ended up doing it

```js
$('html').click(function(event) {

let openMenuButton = $("#menu-open");
let menu = $("#menu-popup");
let both = $('#menu-popup, #menu-open');

    if ( $(event.target).closest(both).length === 0 ) {  
        $(menu).hide();
        console.log("if statement");
        
    } else if ( $(menu).is(":visible") && $(event.target).closest(openMenuButton).length === 1 ){
    $(menu).hide();
    console.log("if ELSE statement");
    } else {
    $(menu).show();
    console.log("ELSE statement");
    }
   
});
```