# Making DropDown menu 'DropUp'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to implement a drop up menu. As a starting point I am using an existing drop down menu built using HTML/CSS/jQuery based on CSS trick's Simple jQuery Dropdowns. (As I couldn't get a pure css one to work on touch devices as they relied on hover states.)

I have made a little bit of progress fiddling with `ul.dropdown ul  {top: -100%; }` but this only moves the dropdown up one 'row', I am not convinced that's semantic css.

Any ideas how I could achieve this ?

I have made a jsfiddle of the problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/TTTb6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

[**Updted jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/AXsfC/)

Comment: NP, it's a long code, things like that are easy to overlook :)

Comment: The only quirk ive noticed is that the menu is now back to front - ie. first item in the css is now last, but its not a particular problem as you can just write the list backwards

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `top`, use `bottom: 100%;`:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For touch devices you need to write code in click event. please check this one here you will get your answer...

[Click to close jQuery dropdown menu on mobile devices while retaining other behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811556/click-to-close-jquery-dropdown-menu-on-mobile-devices-while-retaining-other-beha)

Comment: Of course one has to trigger the event.  The OP knows that.  The OP is asking about styling (positioning) of an element, not how to trigger events.