# Show dropdown in line table above others divs

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, datatables

How can I show the `drop-down` menu in the last row of the table?

When I open the `drop-down` list on the last line of table, it expands and creates a scrollbar. So I have to scroll to see what's in the `drop-down` list.

Here is a jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/y03yxd2q/17/

Thanks for help!

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342911/on-scroll-change-dropdown-menu-drop-position

Comment: that my suggust to loction the dropdown up if scroll

Comment: @לבנימלכה use dropup is not an option because the problem would continue, but this time in the first line https://jsfiddle.net/y03yxd2q/10/

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative top margin to the bottom li span to make the popup higher, like so :

```
td:nth-child(4) > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span
{
  margin-top:-30px;
}
```