# Click outside menu to close is not working

Tags: jquery

I have been reading [some questions at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868582/click-outside-menu-to-close-in-jquery), about how to closing a menu when clicking outside by using jQuery without plugins.

I tried to use `event.stopPropagation()` but is not working. Could you tell me how to use it in the next code, and **explain why is working** in yours?

This is the original code in my webpage, and **I want it to do the same function, plus closing it when clicking outside** ([full code here](https://github.com/gamersmafia/gamersmafia/blob/production/app/assets/javascripts/application.js#L84)):

```
$('.open-popup-on-click').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('popup-id')).toggleClass('hidden');
    return false;
});
```

HTML code (the first div is just a link where users click, and when they do, second div is open as a popup):

```
<div class="topbar-block topbar-profile-options">
  <a class="open-popup-on-click"
    data-popup-id="topbar-user-actions"
    href="/cuenta"><%=avatar_img(@user, :very_small)%></a>
</div>

<div id="topbar-user-actions" class="hidden popup">
  <div style="float: left"><a href="/miembros/<%=@user.login%>"><%=avatar_img(@user, :normal)%></a></div>
  <ul style="display: inline-block">
    <li><a href="/cuenta">mi cuenta</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cuenta/clanes">mis clanes</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cuenta/competiciones">mis competiciones</a></li>
    <li style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;"><a href="/miembros/<%=@user.login%>">mi perfil público</a></li>
    <li><a class="confirm-click nav" href="/cuenta/logout">cerrar sesión</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`open-popup-on-click` is a class used with all links, from where I want to open a popup. In this case, the popup is the second div, with ID `topbar-user-actions`

If you still don't understand me, please look this image:

http://i281.photobucket.com/albums/kk205/LEANDRO351/Gamersmafia/exampleMenu.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to make use of `event.path`. There is an answer over here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/43405204#43405204](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/43405204#43405204)

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things, but this would work

```
           $('body').click(function(event){
                 $('.open-popup-on-click').not(':hidden').toggle();
             });
```

My impression is that you want to close that anchor when a user clicks anywhere else on the page.

Comment: This code is not working, but yes, I want to close it when a user clicks anywhere else on the page. I have added more information to the original question, and also an image. Please, look it: http://i281.photobucket.com/albums/kk205/LEANDRO351/Gamersmafia/exampleMenu.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('click',function(event){
          $('#topbar-user-actions').hide();
       });
```

Comment: If you mean replace the original code with this code, is not working :/

Comment: That's right, `<%=avatar_img(@user, :very_small)%>` is always visible in your example, but if I click **anywhere** the menu is closed. I want the menu to be closed **only** if I click again on the link/image where I clicked to open it, or if I click **outside** the menu, not inside. If this is not working properly due to Fiddle, but should work in my webpage, I don't know how to combine your code, with the original jQuery code of the web page, to work them together. Note I'm starting with jQuery, I didn't make this website, the one who did it didn´t have time to keep working on it. Thanks ;)