# Adding additional drop down menu with Jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a click event with my drop down menu but I seem to only be able to get the first menu to drop down and i can't get it to disappear once I click away from the menu. Any help would be appreciated. I feel like its something easy. Here is my code:

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="clickMe"><a href="#s1">Menu 1</a>
                <span id="s1"></span>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Header a</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Header b</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="clickMe" ><a href="#s2">Menu 2</a>
                <span id="s2"></span>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li ><a href="#">Header c</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Header d</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li ><a href="#s3">Menu 3</a>
                <span id="s3"></span>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Header e</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Subsdfa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Header f</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Header g</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#nav li ul.subs').toggle();

    });
    </script>



   </body>
```

Here is the CSS

```
  * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html {
background-color: #fff;
height: 100%;
 }
body {
color: #333333;
font: 0.75em/1.5em Arial,sans-serif;
 }
.container {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 96%;
}

  /* common and top level styles */
#nav span {
display: none;
}
 #nav, #nav ul {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border-bottom: 5px solid #333333;
float: left;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
position: relative;
width: 98%;
}
#nav ul.subs {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #333333;
display: none;
left: 0;
padding: 2%;
position: absolute;
top: 54px;
width: 96%;
}
 #nav > li {
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
float: left;
margin-bottom: -5px;
text-align: left;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
#nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
-moz-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
white-space: normal;
}
#nav > li > a {
color: #333333;
display: block;
font-size: 1.3em;
line-height: 49px;
padding: 0 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav > li:hover > a, #nav > a:hover {
background-color: #F55856;
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
#nav li.active > a {
background-color: #333333;
color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 /* submenu */
 #nav li:hover ul.subs {
 display: none;
 }


 #nav ul.subs > li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 padding: 10px 2%;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 8%;
  }
 #nav ul.subs > li a {
 color: #777777;
 line-height: 20px;
 }
 #nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #F55856;
 }
 #nav ul.subs > li > a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }
 #nav ul.subs > li li {
 float: none;
 padding-left: 8px;
 -moz-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
 -ms-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
 -o-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
 -webkit-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
 transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
  }
 #nav ul.subs > li li:hover {
  padding-left: 15px;
  }
```

Thanks for any advice. I just want the navigation to drop down when I click on it and stay there until I click away or go to the next menu.

Comment: `clickMe` Id should be unique. you can place classname to set comman all the element you want

Comment: doesn't work for me. It drops down the wrong menu as well when I do that, it seems to be dropping down the last set of <li>

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/eTMbj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove all the repeating ID's. By definition ID must be unique. Change to class instead

You can try this:

```
 $('#nav > li').click(function () {
      $(this).siblings().find('ul.subs').hide();
      $(this).find('ul.subs').toggle();
  });
```

it accomplishes open/close on click. However it might be more user friendly using `hover`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AXvb2/)**</kbd>

Similar but using `hover`

```
 $('#nav > li').hover(function () {
      $(this).siblings().find('ul.subs').hide();
      $(this).find('ul.subs').show();
  },function(){
       $(this).find('ul.subs').show();
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AXvb2/1/)**</kbd>

Note: hover version can be accomplished with no script using CSS only

Comment: Thank you both of you. I am still very new to this so I appreciate the help. One more thing that I could use help on is to remove the box once the user clicks off the screen. I have tried this approach but haven't seem to be able to make it quite work. Any help would be appreciated.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868582/click-outside-menu-to-close-in-jquery

Comment: if use hover don't even have to worry about it. see this demo for using click ... http://jsfiddle.net/AXvb2/2/