# Closing menu by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got small menu, which I want to automatic close on clicking anywhere on the page. I know it's probably a matter of adding one line of code, but everything I've tried so far doesn't work...

Now it is simply js function:

```
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

---

Edit: sorry, Sorry, I didn't know I could edit the first post... Here's the rest of the code:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <h2>Position #1</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #2</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #3</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #4</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #5</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #6</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #7</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #8</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #9</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>Position #10</a>
  </h2>
</div>
<span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;Menu</span>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<h2>Position #1</a></h2>
<h2>Position #2</a></h2>
<h2>Position #3</a></h2>
<h2>Position #4</a></h2>
<h2>Position #5</a></h2>
<h2>Position #6</a></h2>
<h2>Position #7</a></h2>
<h2>Position #8</a></h2>
<h2>Position #9</a></h2>
<h2>Position #10</a></h2>
</div>

<span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;Menu</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the things that you have tried in your question.

Comment: This will help you, only thing is it works with jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868582/click-outside-menu-to-close-in-jquery

Comment: Refer to this link : https://codepen.io/alexgill/pen/EWWojp

Comment: the takeaway point is to attach a click listener to the `html`, then check and close menu if it's visible

Answer (score 3):

To hide an element you should use `style.display = "none"`:

```
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}
```

To show it again, put the display back to what is was. A lot of the time it's `block`:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
}
```

In your case, since you don't provide enough code I'm going to assume you also need to know where to call your `closeNav` function. You could do that on the document:

```
document.onclick = function() {
    closeNav();
}
```

And here's the solution based on the code you provided:

```js
document.onclick = function(evt) {
  if (!event.target.matches("#menu")) {
    closeNav();
  }
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <h2>Position #1</h2>
    <h2>Position #2</h2>
    <h2>Position #3</h2>
    <h2>Position #4</h2>
    <h2>Position #5</h2>
    <h2>Position #6</h2>
    <h2>Position #7</h2>
    <h2>Position #8</h2>
    <h2>Position #9</h2>
    <h2>Position #10</h2>
  </div>

  <span id="menu" style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;Menu</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong all the time because it stops working at all...

Comment: What stops working? The example you gave is only a small part of your code. It's hard for me to guess what is happening.

Comment: @vicxo edited my answer with a working solution based on the edit you made.

Comment: @vicxo mark it as correct by clicking the check mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display= "none";
}
```