# How to close Hamburger menu when clicked outside the menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working some code, where I use Hamburger responsive menu. The menu opens and closes when clicked on the hamburger icon. I wanted to add a functionality for closing the menu when clicked outside the menu. I managed to close the menu when clicked outside but without the close animation.

Here is the JS code that I tried:

```
   $(document).on("click", function () {
      $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("show");
    });
```

and the HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg tm-navbar" id="tmNav">
    <div class="container">
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-bars navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
      </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            A
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            B
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            C
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            D
          </li>            
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The above JS code closes the menu when clicked outside the menu but without the animations. I would like to close the menu with the closing animation. Would appreciate some help with this issue.

Comment: You're using Bootstrap, right?

Comment: Can you show the CSS that has the animation?

Comment: Read this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868582/click-outside-menu-to-close-in-jquery

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is [Bootstrap's Collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse) (which it looks like considering the `collapse` and `navbar-collapse` classes), you don't want to remove the `show` class yourself. As you found out, that will skip all the other work Bootstrap does; including animating the transition.

Instead, use the provided [`.collapse('hide')`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#collapsehide) event to cause Bootstrap to close the Collapse for you.

```js
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('#navbarSupportedContent').collapse('hide');
});
```